# What is the optimal way to map a query result from Entity Framework to my own model classes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an SQL Server Express 2012 with the following event model in the Entity Framework:

eventPage: ID, name, description ..
eventDates: IDEvent, DateStart, DateEnd ..
eventTopics: IDEvent IDTopic ..
topics: ID, name, description..

So eventDates has an eventPage property and eventPage has an IEnumerable and eventTopic has a topic property and so on.

I want to make a query throuth the model and the result map it to my custom classes in C#.
I dont want to use the model classes generated by the EF, i have some classes with the only properties i need. ie:

Topic: ID, Name
EventDate: DateStart, DateEnd
Event: ID, Name, Topics, Start, End

Being Topics a List of Topic and Dates a List of EventDates

I have a method that makes the query and returns a IQueryable and from it i want a List.

So the way i get it is:

```
var events=GetEvents(start, end);
var eventsList = (from ev in events
                  select new {event = ev, eventPage = ev.eventPage,topics=ev.eventTopics)).ToList();
//Mapping
var map = (from ev in eventsList
select new Event(ev.event,ev.eventPage,ev.topics)).ToList();
```

And in the constructor i set the properties:

```
this.name=eventPage.Name;
this.start=event.Start;
this.end=event.End;
this.topics = topics.Select(t=>t.Topic).ToList();
```

But this is a bit slow for a large number of events, i would like to know if there is a more optimus way.

At the beginning the constructor only parameter was the event and inside i got the event.eventPage.Name , etc but it was too slow so i get the data i need first and after it i call the constructor.

Comment: Why you don't want to use the mapped classes? You have to have a really good reason for coding all your model twice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) is your friend in such situation.

I suggest you read the [Getting Started guide](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started). It's pretty simple to understand and you'll be able to map from your query to your custom DTOs really fast.

Here's the full [Wiki guide](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki). See [Lists and Arrays](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays).

In your case it'd be something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Event, MyCustomEvent>();

var events =
    Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Event>, IEnumerable<MyCustomEvent>>(Database.Events).
    AsQueryable();
```

`AutoMapper` also allows you to do something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Event, MyCustomEvent>().
ForMember(dest => dest.SomeCollectionProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RelationshipProperty.SomeCollectionProperty));
```

It's really powerful! Entity Framework for example let's you lazy load related entities by default and so I think the examples above work out of the box with a single query to the database to get the root object.

Comment: Thanks Leniel, i know AutoMapper and have used for simpler examples. My doubt is how can i get the properties i need (only the ones i need) and the related objects i need in only one query and after map it. I think it is a bit slow becouse it is making several queries to the db after the initial query. May it be?

Comment: @tito.icreativos If that's what you're worried about, then you may want to [`Include`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx) the `topics` collection.

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor thats interesting, i didnt know about include. How could i debug the final sql that is executed to check what is exactly retrieving and if it is optimus? is there a way to trace it? I would like to know if after the query and in the mapping is there some more queries launched to the db.

Comment: @tito.icreativos I guess the easiest way would be to write a simpler version of your example (like e.g. manually 'mapping' few classes) in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), it can show you the SQL generated from LINQ.